# pushing a partially transparent UIView into a UINavigationController so the formerly pushed UIView is also visible.

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView that contains a search Bar which takes the top 1/5 the iPhone screen (portrait layout).
I want to add a results UIView  below the search bar, without hiding the search bar.
can these be managed using a UINavigationController? I've been doing some experiments, and as far as I understand, a pushed UIView will always hide the ones that were pushed before.
I will be happy to find that I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true, when you push a view controller using UINavigationController, previous view controller will always be hidden. Even you present a viewcontroller with transparent view as a modal view controller, parent view controller will not be visible. But I don't think you really need this. Search bar and showing results view should be handled within one view controller.
I suggest you just add your "results view" as a subview from the very begging, but keep it hidden until you need it.

Comment: yeah, I can do that, but I actually have 3 more views, as I can switch between 2 kinds of results from 2 search engines, and also after viewing the results, I can click on one of them and see its details, in another view. That's why I wanted to use a UINavigation controller.

Comment: so why don't you keep search bar & results in one view controller, and details in the second view controller? Here use of UINavigation controller is totally justified.